# Dynamic expression in nested aura iteration in Salesforce Lightning

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx, salesforce1-app, aura-iteration

I've two objects:

```
listContent: [{'Id':1,'Name':'SF'},{'Id':2,'Name':'DS'}]
fields:['Id','Name']
```

Now I'm using nested aura iteration to display the listContent as shown below:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.listContent}" var="s">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.fields}" var="i">
        <p>{!(s[i])}</p>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:iteration>
```

I'm not able to display values of the fields coming from inner loop from object coming from outer loop. Kindly help, how to combine them both.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do isn't allowed in Aura. Instead, you need to convert your data into a an Array of Arrays.

```
var output = listContent.map(
  row => fields.map(
    field => row[field]
  )
);
```

Which you would then iterate over each row, and in each row, you'd iterate over each element.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.output}" var="row">
    <aura:iteration items="{!row}" var="field">
        <p>{!field}</p>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:iteration>
```